# How can I find files what I need in branch what I choose in git?

Tags: git

In git, I want to find files, I want to choose a branch.
for example, look at below.

```
git diff --name-status comitaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..comitbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
M    fileA.txt   // it was changed in xxx branch.
M    fileB.txt   // it was changed in yyy branch.
M    fileC.txt   // it was changed in zzz branch.
```

if I wanted to find fileB.txt, how can I use the git command?

Comment: `git diff` doesn't know about branches. It compares commits and their trees. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to find files that changed in yyy branch.

Comment: change in reference to what? The current commit, a different branch? If the file changes in yyy branch and is then changed back to its initial state (or your reference point contains identical changes in a different commit), do you want to still see it?

Answer (score 2):

Files aren't changed in *branches*, in Git.  In fact, files aren't even *stored* in branches.  Files are stored in *commits*.

You might wonder what good branches are, in Git.  You probably *should* wonder, because branches aren't really much good at all in Git—though this depends on how, exactly, you define *branch*, because the word *branch* itself is ambiguous, in Git.  There's a better-defined term, *branch name*, that you might want to use instead.  What *branch names* do, in Git, is allow you—and Git—to *find* commits.  The reason for this is that the true name of a commit is a big, ugly, random-looking number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), impossible for humans to remember or deal with.

> ```
> git diff --name-status xxx..yyy
> ```

Note: this means the same thing as:

```
git diff --name-status xxx yyy
```

The `xxx` and `yyy` here are *commit hash IDs*, or *something that resolves to a commit hash ID*, such as a branch name.  Git needs these so that it can find the two specific commits.

Git then *extracts both commits*.  Each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*, so this produces two different snapshots.  Git then compares the two snapshots:

- If some file is in both snapshots, and is *the same* in both snapshots, Git says nothing at all about that file.
- If some file exists in only one of the two snapshots, Git will—usually<sup>1</sup>—tell you that the file was created (exists in `yyy`, missing in `xxx`) or deleted (exists in `xxx`, missing in `yyy`).
- If the file exists in both snapshots, Git will (again, usually) tell you that the file was modified, and show you some set of changes that, if applied to the left-side (`xxx`) copy, will produce the right-side (`yyy`) copy.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say *usually* because there are a lot of corner cases, including, e.g., `--name-only`, where the status is dropped, or *rename detection*, where a file that went missing on the left is matched up with a newly created file on the right, as a rename operation.

---

> ```
> M    fileA.txt   // it was changed in xxx branch.
> M    fileB.txt   // it was changed in yyy branch.
> M    fileC.txt   // it was changed in zzz branch.
> ```

The comments here imagine something that is simply not findable: `M` just means that these three files exist in both left and right side commits, but have different contents.

Any one commit can exist in multiple different branches.  Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, so no file is ever changed *in* a commit.  Files are changed *between two commits*, or aren't changed between those two commits.

At the same time, though, each commit also holds information saying which particular commit hash ID(s) are the *immediate predecessor* of that commit.  So if we have a string of commits, all in a row, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

we can have Git start at commit `H` and work backwards:

- First, we have Git use commit `H` to locate commit `G`, and compare the two snapshots.  For whatever files are *different in these two commits*, we claim that these files are *changed in commit `H`*.  This is just a way of looking at things—commit `H` is purely a snapshot, not changes, but by comparing it to an earlier snapshot, we can see it *as* changes.
- Then, we have Git use commit `H` to locate commit `G` again, but this time we now consider commit `G` on its own.  It has an earlier commit `F` recorded, so we have Git use `G` to locate `F` and *compare the two snapshots*.  Whatever is different, we claim is "changed in `G`", as before.
- Of course, `G`'s parent commit `F` is an ordinary commit as well, with some earlier commit (presumably `E`).  We repeat this process, over and over again.

If these three commits are only found by starting at branch name `feature`, people claim that the files were "changed in branch `feature`":

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D--E--F--G--H   <-- feature
```

But here's the weird thing about Git branch names: we can create and destroy them *at any time*.  Let's create a name, `zorg`, right now and make it point to commit `G`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D--E--F--G   <-- zorg
                  \
                   H   <-- feature
```

The set of *commits* in this repository is unchanged.  All commits are frozen for all time: no part of *any* commit can *ever* change.  So the changes between commits `F` and `G`, which we said were `feature`-branch changes a moment ago ... well, they're still there, between `F` and `G`, but now they're `zorg`-branch changes.

What this means is that *unless you hold the branch names fixed too* (which Git doesn't, on purpose), you can't say that some change is due to some *branch*.  It's merely due to some set of *commits*.  Don't ask about *branches;* ask about *commits*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so you said a comit dosen't have a branch info?

Comment: I thought I could see a branch info like below.
https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/commit/8238c906f43ea003a430a1dd8f4caea03e734811
I can see bugfix/699. but, a commit doesn't have a branch info, does it?

Comment: There's a one-way map: a branch name holds a hash ID. After that, all you have are hash IDs, all the way back. We sometimes say that a branch name *contains* all the commits that you can reach by starting from the branch tip commit (stored in the name) and working backwards. See also [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Comment: Bravo, once again!